# Fallo comunicación pymodbusTCP.client ocasional-Nonetype

Tags: tkinter

necesito ayuda con una app que estoy desarrollando con Tkinter. En ella se van realizando lecturas y escrituras en un micro de una tarjeta electrónica con diferentes comunicaciones. Todo va bien hasta que llego a la comunicación Modbus TCPIP. Establezco la comunicación y realizo varias lecturas de registros del mapa de memorias del micro (a través de un módulo DIGI previamente sincronizado). Todo correcto hasta ahí, pero la cuarta vez que me comunico mediante este protocolo, primero intento escribir en la dirección deseada, y a continuación la intento leer para comprobar que ha sido correcta la escritura. Esta escritura y lectura la debo realizar varias veces consecutivas en otros registros con otros valores. Aquí aparece el problema, **unas veces lo hace bien**, **pero la mayoría me da un error--TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Ya que el registro que lee es None**,por lo que parece. He probado a meter timeout, sleep....y nada. No sé si con estos datos alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: Para ayudarte, necesitas poner el código que estas usando. Nadie sabe realmente que estas haciendo mal

Comment: Gracias, pero encontré el problema. Al escribir y leer, para comprobar lo escrito, tenía que darle un tiempo. Ahora va bien. Gracias, de nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el problema. Al escribir y leer, para comprobar lo escrito, tenía que darle un tiempo. Ahora va bien.

Simplemente le di un `time.sleep` en cada llamada a la lectura y/o escritura y también le introduje una función para que si la lectura era "None" lo reintentase 4 veces, por ejemplo, con otro retardo de 0.5 segundos.

Comment: Tengo otro problema...Con cada ejecución de la app debo leer la MAC del equipo conectado en remoto, crear .dat con dicha MAC, y luego ejecutar dos .bat para sincronizar el DIGI y el equipo a testear (llaman a un ejecutable/cargan y reinician el DIGI/comprueban la MAC...no sé muy bien ). Si lo hago manualmente (una vez cargado en el .dat la MAC hago doble click en los .bat) comunica correctamente mi app y el equipo. Pero si lo hago con mi script ('subprocess.call' a cda .bat) no. En la consola se ve result_SUCCESS con cada .bat pero no comunica, como si no hubieran ejecutado los .bat.

Comment: El problema era que uno de los tres archivos NO lo tenía en la carpeta del script....